# How can I check if an input is on a certain line of a .txt file?

Tags: python, text-files

I am creating a simple quiz program in python using text files to store the questions and answers. Is there a way to check if an input is on line 3 of a text file (for example).

I have tried other methods that work but they check the whole file or the first three lines instead of just line 3. (Note: I am also getting an index error - string index out of range using the code below)

Any help?

Text file for answers:

[image]

Text file for questions:

[image]

Error:

[image]

```
def questions():

    question_answered = 0  # sets number of questions answered to zero
    lineq = 6  # sets the number of lines to output from questions.txt
    linea = 0  # sets the number of linea to read from answers.txt
    score = 0  # sets initial score to 0

    with open("questions.txt", "r") as q:
        with open("answers.txt", "r") as a:
            while question_answered != 3:

                linea += 1
                question_answered += 1

                for i in range(lineq):
                    line = (q.readline())
                    print(line)

                response = input("answer:")

                check_line = a.readline()

                if response in check_line[linea]:
                    score += 1
                    print("correct")
                    print(check_line[linea])

                print("score:", score)


questions()
```

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Reading the same files over and over is extremely inefficient. Just read all your data into memory once at the start of the program, and examine variables in memory instead of lines in disk files.

Comment: Read both files into memory as previously suggested. However, given the data that you've shown, you'll need to make this rather more elaborate because you're searching for a single character in a string that may exist elsewhere other than at offset 1. That could lead to incorrect results

Comment: update: I got it to work thanks guys! @Andy Knight+triplee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using this snippet: (where f is the file object)

```
lines = f.readlines()
```

Now `lines` is a `list` object with strings for each line.
Note that they end in `"\n"`

Maybe reading from the file at the beginning of the program and then using local program memory will be easier.